# why does my javascript prompt always return the default on iOS devices

Tags: javascript, ios

I have this very straight forward snippet of code in the head section of a page:

```
        <script>
            var mrVar;
            var mrComparator="someString";
            mrVar=prompt('Please enter code word to view this page',' ');
            if (mrVar != mrComparator){
                window.location="http://www.google.com";
            } else {console.log('they are equal');
                alert("Code Word Correct. Click OK to view.");
                }       
    </script>
```

Works great in every browser, but on iOS devices (ipad, iphone both running iOS 6) the comparison fails whether in mobile safari or chrome, and google is displayed. I can see that mrVar is always returning the default (a single space) or if no default is set it returns null, but again, only on iOS.

Comment: I don't have an iOS device to test, but I am surprised that this code should work on *any* device. You assign the password to `mrPass`, but then compare `mrVar`. `mrVar` has never been set and is always `null`.

Comment: Sorry, bad copy/paste editing on my part. I've edited the code in question to reflect the actual code in the snippet.

Comment: mrPass ? assuming your are speaking of mrVar

Comment: The code was edited, I made an error in the original post in that I forgot to rename the var asked for in the prompt.

Comment: OK, now it makes more sense to me ;-) Unfortunately, I cannot help you here, because I do not have an iOS device to test.

Comment: Have you try something like `alert(prompt("test"));` and see the result ?

Comment: mathk you are brilliant! 

I found that since I was using a default on the prompt it was putting a single space in front of the input on iOS devices that just wasn't noticeable in the UI. 

In the desktop browsers it was clearing this space when the input field got focus.